# AddProximityAlert Disappears Although Expiration -1

Tags: android, proximity

I want my app to have a proximityAlert until the user removes it.  I use expiration -1 to create this proximityAlert.  The proximityAlert
works.  But I find on my Droid phone, after adding a proximityAlert
and leaving the phone over night for charging, the proximityAlert does
not work the next day.  How can I make sure that my proximityAlert is
active indefinitely unless the user removes it?

Answer (score 1):

The proximity alert uses a long variable for expiration.  Are you putting the number -1 in the proximityAlert or a variable declared as long that equals -1?  Maybe using a long variable instead of -1 will fix it.

addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, float radius, **long expiration**, PendingIntent intent)

Answer (score 1):

LocationManager uses a `HashMap<PendingIntent,ProximityAlert>` to store their Alerts.
See code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.3.7_r1/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java#174).

1) ProximityAlert uses your provided PendingIntent as key
if you add 2 ProximityAlert for 2 coordinates but with same PendingIntent then only the last Proximity alert will works.

2) `removeProximityAlert(PendingIntent pIntent)` has to be used to remove the Alerting.